# Why the return is a item of the list, not the list itsef

Tags: python

I write a function "getlist()" in a python (Version 2.7) file named test.py like this:

```
d_list = []
def getlist(a):
    b = int(a) + 7
    c = [b, b + 9, b + 2*9, b + 3*9]
    for i in c:
        text = "%s" % i
        d_list.append(text)

    return d_list
```

The good news is it works well with a list as return, but bad news is that it will become bigger and bigger like this:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.getlist(1980)
['1987', '1996', '2005', '2014']
>>> test.getlist(1990)
['1987', '1996', '2005', '2014', '1997', '2006', '2015', '2024']
```

Obviously, the returned list will include all that have returned. Then, I change the function with the idea: give it a condition, if there have been returns in the list, just clear them firstly. The changed codes are like this:

```
d_list = []
def getlist(a):
    b = int(a) + 7
    c = [b, b + 9, b + 2*9, b + 3*9]
    for i in c:
        text = "%s" % i
    if d_list:
        d_list[:] = []
        d_list.append(text)

    else:
        d_list.append(text)

    return d_list
```

But now, the function couldn't work as I expected. For example:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.getlist(1980)
['2014']
>>> test.getlist(1990)
['2024']
```

It only returns the item of a list, the max value of it. How could I get a list as return? Thank you.

Comment: `d_list` here is not a local variable, move it into the local scope of the function in the first snippet and it should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piggy backing on other great answers here is the use of a python list comprehension:

```
def getlist(a):
    b = int(a) + 7
    d_list = [str(b  + multiplier * 9) for multiplier in range(0,4)]
    return d_list
```

Answer (score 2):

And that's the reason concept of local variable was invented.

```
def getlist(a):
    d_list = []
    b = int(a) + 7
    c = [b, b + 9, b + 2*9, b + 3*9]
    for i in c:
        text = "%s" % i
        d_list.append(text)

    return d_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on ravi's answer, you can make your code more efficient by using this:

```
def getlist(a):
    d_list = []
    b = int(a) + 7
    d_list = [str(b), str(b + 9), str(b + 2*9), str(b + 3*9)]

    return d_list
```

The `str(b), str(b+9), etc...` casts your values as strings as they are put into the list, which is more efficient than iterating through your `c` list with a `for` loop and then appending those new values to `d_list`.

Comment: or simply 

`def getlist(a):    

    b = int(a) + 7

    return [str(b), str(b + 9), str(b + 2*9), str(b + 3*9)]`

Comment: It's more pythonic (and easier to read) to return a variable than an absolute value like you're suggesting.